# How to post a form to a php page?

Tags: php, jquery, json, post, html

I want to post a form with two fields on a php page using $_POST['json']; the object will be json type. Can you help me?

```
<div id="result"></div>
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" >
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br/>
    Number: <input type="text" name="number" id="number"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit!" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to send json via post, you need to script it using js or jquery

throw `JSON.stringify(values)` into your function. You can grab the form data fast with `var values = $("form").serialize();`.

I think you're really asking about ajax or php post returning json... This example should cover both scenarios with some tweaking.

**index.php**

```
<?
    $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "";
    $number = isset($_POST["number"]) ? $_POST["number"] : "";
    $fromAjax = isset($_POST["ajax"]) ? $_POST["ajax"] : NULL;
    if($name != "" || $number != ""){
        $results = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'number' => $number
        );

        $resultFromPHP = json_encode($results);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="resultfromphp" style="border: 1px solid;width:300px;height:25px; ">
    <? echo isset($resultFromPHP) ? $resultFromPHP : ""; //if result is set, echo it, else empty?>
</div>
<br>
<div id="resultfromajax" style="border: 1px solid;width:300px;height:25px;">
</div>
<hr>
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" >
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br/>
    Number: <input type="text" name="number" id="number"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="PHP Submit!" name="php_submit" id="php_submit"/>
    <input type="button" value="AJAX Submit!" name="ajax_submit" id="ajax_submit"/>
</form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="submit.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

for the php method, you put the php code in the document itself, and submit to self. you can use includes to keep the code separated. Using the html submit, you can't convert the form data before sending. What I wrote at the top should cover that. what will happen here is the data is sent post, and converted to json there.

ajax method is pretty much the same, however since you're using jquery with this part you can make json first, send and receive json back.

**submit.js**

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("#ajax_submit").on("click", function(){
        sendSomeAjax();
    });
});

var sendSomeAjax = function(){
    var sendData = $("form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        type: "post",
        data: sendData,
        success: function(data){
            $("#resultfromajax").html(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            $("#resultfromajax").html("There was an error.");
        }
    });
};
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php

    $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "";
    $number = isset($_POST["number"]) ? $_POST["number"] : "";
    $fromAjax = isset($_POST["ajax"]) ? $_POST["ajax"] : NULL;
    if($name != "" || $number != ""){
        $results = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'number' => $number
        );

        echo json_encode($results);
    }
```